# What happens when we get latest version of the excluded file in TFS? Will that get updated?

Tags: git, tfs, version-control

I have a web.config file excluded in my solution, when i take get latest version, will that get updated and will i have the web config file same as in the server or it doesn't gets updated??

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: It is so clear my question! why do want to down vote? What happens to the excluded files when you take get latest version? @fabian h

Comment: If the file is on disk, but simply excluded from the project, then if you get latest on that file you will get the latest version of the file. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it answers my question! but my web config never showed any conflicts result nor got the latest version. Is that happens sometimes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean by excluded

If your web.config file is not in tfs source control at all (excluded from source control) - then getting latest from source control will not change your file

If your web.config file is in source control, but excluded from your project (excluded from the current open project) - then getting latest from source control may alter the file (this depends on what you got latest on and where the web.config file actually lives). For example if your Web.config file lives in $/MyTFS/Code and the open project is in $/MyTFS/Code/Projects, and you get latest on $/MyTFS/Code/Projects then the web.config file won't be changed.

If your web.config file is in source control, and it's part of the current project, and you have local changes that are excluded in your "Pending Changes" view in Team Explorer (excluded from pending changes) - then when you get latest, if there are changes to web.config, TFS will merge those changes with your version of the file. If there are conflicts, you will have to resolve those conflicts manually (Visual Studio will show a resolve conflicts dialog). At the end of that process the web.config file will still be checked out locally and excluded.

Comment: Thanks for the help! that answers my question